# Telerik: ScrollView Taghelper not Seen/Located

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, kendo-ui, telerik

I am looking for the ScrollView Taghelper in Telerik Net Core.

For Button, it is ButtonTagHelper. I can all the corresponding members and parameters.

For Date, it is DatePickerTagHelper class.

What is it for ScrollView, I did not locate or see a ScrollViewTagHelper class.

https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/tag-helpers/media/scrollview/overview

Did not Locate here in **Class**,

[image]

I did not see in **View** either,

[image]

Looking for Taghelper like this, example for Button,

```
public class ButtonTagHelper : TagHelperBase
{
    public ButtonTagHelper(IKendoHtmlGenerator generator);

    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public string OnClick { get; set; }
    public bool? Enable { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public string IconClass { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string SpriteCssClass { get; set; }

    protected override string GetInitializationScript();
    protected override Dictionary<string, object> SerializeEvents();
    protected override Dictionary<string, object> SerializeSettings();
    protected override void WriteHtml(TagHelperOutput output);
```

Comment: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-core/scrollview/tag-helper  This is what they have on their website.

Comment: I saw that, I am looking for all the class and all its members and methods, thanks, you will see those for eg ButtonTagHelper from Telerik

Comment: Ahh. To be honest I don't think it exists.  Submit a ticket to Telerik to confirm but I am using KendoUI for a project and I have been dealing with the splotchy documentation as well.  It seems to me like they randomly leave out documentation for components and have very different levels of depth on everything.

Comment: @Kevin are you using trial version or Official? Do you see it on your latest official version for June 2019? Thanks,

Comment: I am using the Official version.  I have been using ASP.Net MVC have been experiencing the same lack of documentation issues.  I did a quick glance through the 2019 version and did not see anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the latest version of Telerik UI for ASP.NET Core referenced in your project.

The scrollview is a relatively new widget, I think it came out in 2019. It is likely that your project is referencing an older version and this is why you don't see it in the intellisense.

You can also look at the Kendo UI for jQuery API reference to see the available properties and methods and events, as this is where it all comes from, UI for ASP.NET Core is wrappers over the jQuery widgets. Here's the link for the scrollview: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scrollview. This applies to all widgets, not just the scrollview, of course.

Comment: hi @rdmptn thanks, can you help me with this question also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57069066/net-core-create-tagbuilder-for-kendo-telerik-scrollview